# "apt-get: command not found" issue raspberrry pi os built using Buildroot

Tags: raspberry-pi3, cross-compiling, embedded-linux, apt-get, buildroot

I have built a sdcard.img for raspberry pi using Buildroot. When I run apt-get command it throws error "apt-get: command not found". I did not find apt-get/dpkg package to enable in 'make menuconfig' options. Now I'm trying to run cross-compiled opencv program on my Rpi but some shared libraries are missing and I want to install these libraries using apt repository (as I already did it on standard Raspbian Stretch os & program run successfully).

I googled it, there's no solution for Buildroot rasbpbian os. Also I tried downloading and installing .deb packages for apt/apt-get/dpkg, didn't work.

apt-get: command not found

I want to cross-compile a kernel which will have all the necessary packages such as apt/dpkg, bin and lib files. Or for the time being to get the work done need guidance to install apt/dpkg packages on Rpi buildroot os.

Answer (score 2):

Buildroot will never have apt or any package manager. With buildroot you have to decide ahead-of-time what packages you'll want included in your rootfs. Use Raspbian if you want to use apt-get.

Comment: I have Raspbian stretch os, but there's reason behind using buildroot image. I will run my code in the start up script. My project is gonna be big so I'll have to 'make' it locally and cross-compile the kernel.

Answer (score 1):

With a Buildroot-generated system, it is not possible to use a package manager, because there is no way to make sure the package binaries will actually work on your system. There are two reasons for this:

- Binaries depend on the toolchain (C library, kernel header version, subarchitecture choices, ABI choices). There are hundreds of combinations of these choices possible in Buildroot, it's not possible to build package binaries for all of them. Traditional distros limit the choices to just one per architecture.
- How one package is configured affects how other packages can be built. Again, Buildroot offers choices there, while traditional distros choose one (usually enable all features).

In Buildroot, instead of using apt-get, you'd go back to `make menuconfig`, select the additional packages you want to install, and rebuild the system.

Comment: Hello @Luca Ceresoli, @Arnout, I have a question regarding buildroot. I have a debian package (x64) and I need to install it on my target. I have a `opkg` package manager on my target. Can I use this to install debian packages? Will the debian package work out-of-the-box on buildroot based Linux?

Comment: I think opkg can be used to install .deb files (they use the same format). However, it's quite likely that it won't work, because the debian package will be linked with some shared libraries that don't exist on you Buildroot-based system.

Answer (score 1):

robert-orr has already answered your question but I think you are confused about the naming. You cannot rebuild raspbian using buildroot.

Rebuilding raspbian (a debian derivative) is a fairly involved process. You have to implement bootstrapping of a distro (compile a compiler, compile your packages with your compiled compiler, etc.) See [Debian Bootstrap](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianBootstrap) for everything needed to create your own distro from source. This is usually done by debian and debian-derivative distributions only.

You can build a simpler image using Buildroot, if that satisfies your needs. Also look at [Yocto/OE](https://www.yoctoproject.org/) to see if that satisfies your requirement for building an image from source.